Why does my Python script say "File not found" even though the file exists?
I'm working on a Python project using PyCharm, and my script is supposed to read a file located on my desktop. However, when I run the script, I get the error message:
File not found. Please check the file path and try again.

Here is my Python code:
import os

file_path = r"C:\Users\HP\Desktop\new_file.txt"

if os.path.exists(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        contents = file.read()
        print(contents)
else:
    print("File not found. Please check the file path and try again.")

I double-checked that the file new_file.txt exists on my desktop. The file path in the script matches the file's properties, and the file extension is .txt. I've also verified that the file name has no hidden characters or extra spaces.
I have attached a screenshot showing the file properties confirming the location and name of the file:

I've also run the script as an administrator to rule out permission issues.
Despite these checks, the script still says the file is not found.
Are there any common issues or pitfalls with os.path.exists() that I might be overlooking?
Could this issue be related to PyCharm or the Python environment I'm using?
Is there any way to debug this further to pinpoint the problem?

What does listing the directory contents (e.g. with os.listdir) show?

"Are there any common issues or pitfalls with os.path.exists() that I might be overlooking?" Yes, but not in this context. In concurrent code the file might be created/deleted between the os.path.exists and open calls. In general it is safer to just try open ing the file and handle the exception if one is raised

Probably some caching issue...Try Restarting the IDE

Try to eliminate any potential issue with PyCharm by running the script in a terminal - e.g., python your_script.py

my bet: multiple accounts involved (administrator... oh boy, that's probably it). or you're one of those kinds that have weird letter lookalikes that aren't the originals.

y'all, clearly the open didn't fail because it wasn't even called. the exists() said False already.

or you're (pycharm is) running this in WSL... :D yeah that's a definite possibiilty. I hate these guessing games.

The bad way is reinstalled the Pycharm
